# Remove Windows completely replace Ubuntu without deleting Personal Files

Tags: uninstall

I am currently running `Windows 8.1`. And want to install `Ubuntu 16.10` in my machine. But to do that, I have three options-

```
1. Install Ubuntu alongside Windows
2. Erase all and Install Ubuntu
3. Something else
```

I don't want to dual boot with `Windows`. I want to remove it and have only `Ubuntu`. But Second option will erase my all personal data. I don't want that to.
So, What can I do???

Comment: Most obvious answer: create a backup before you delete partitions and restore it into Ubuntu when done installing it.

Comment: Do you have your windows installation partitioned? Are your data at separated partition? in case they are, you can do what you ask for. Let me know,  if I should post the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is copy your personal files from your Windows installation to an external storage device, then you can erase everything and install Ubuntu.

Comment: :( , But Thanks for help @carlos